# HTML - Input range for integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible as to create an inputfield to get a range of numbers (int) with fixed strings placed in the inputfield ("from" and "to") like daterangepicker does?
[Datepicker on GitHub](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) 
(From 20.02.2000 To 30.02.2000) = Daterankepicker.
(From 34 To 200) = My wish.

Question: Is there a jQuery-Plugin like "numberRangePicker"?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For number range selection you can use other interactive widget like slider (easy to use). Check this link http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/demo.html